# Reading a CT with burden resistor and voltmeter, why am I getting this reading?

Tags: current-measurement

So I have hooked up a 50:5A CT, with only the hot wire going through its center. I put a 1 Ohm burden resister between the legs of the CT and then measured the voltage on each side of that resistor.

The primary is 120V @ 60Hz.

Since I used a 1 Ohm resistor, the voltage reading should be roughly equal the the current across the CT. I read 183mV, so I would expect ~180mA, which equates to about 1.8A on the primary wire going through the CT.

Two separate clamp-on amp probes both read 3.3A on the primary. I'm confused as to why my voltage reading is not more like 330mV. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: CT]

Note: My meter says that the actual resistance value of the resistor is 1.1 Ohm.

Comment: (1) What is the VA rating of the CT? (2) Is there a maximum burden specified? (3) Post a link to the datasheet if you can.

Comment: @Transistor Here's the datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/276003.pdf

Comment: @marcelm 60Hz @ 120V

Comment: Try 100 ohms, and see what happens.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: That's tending towards an open-circuit which you generally *don't* want to do on a CT. Why are you suggesting it?

Comment: @Transistor - Well, OK, 10 ohms. Talema, for instance, uses 33 ohms as their standard burden resistor for 500:5 A current transformers. I suggest it simply because a lot of meters are pretty bad at very low AC voltages. I'll grant that 100 ohms is too large in this case (3.24 watts on the resistor), but 10 ohms will give 1.8 volts and 0.3 watts, which seems a decent compromise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are exceeding the VA rating. With your photo now added we can see the rating is 1.0 VA. That will be the maximum power you can draw from the CT with the rated secondary current, 5 A in this case.

From \$ P = I^2R \$ we can calculate the maximum burden resistance as follows:

$$ R = \frac {P}{I^2} = \frac {1}{5^2} = 0.04 \; \Omega $$

Since you have a burden of 1 Ω you may be presenting too high a burden on the secondary and the core of the CT may be saturating - although this would be surprising at < 10% primary current.

If you have another 1 Ω resistor add it in parallel and see if the accuracy improves (remembering to double the meter reading).

---

Notes:

- At rated current and a 0.04 Ω burden you will get \$ V = IR = 5 \times 0.04 = 0.2 \; V_{RMS} \$ across your burden resistor.
- You may be able to make a 0.04 Ω resistor from a length of solid-copper network or telephone cable if you know the wire gauge. You'll find a cable resistance calculator online fairly easily.
- When your burden is right you can increase the primary ampere turns by looping your primary cable through several times. e.g., 3.3 A with 10 turns should read the same as 33 A, single turn.

Comment: Ok, so I tested with this setup: https://image.ibb.co/fNnKGk/20170829_152626.jpg and got a reading of 114mV, which when doubled (228mV) is more accurate. I think you're onto something here. Thanks!

Comment: See the notes. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: So I just tried 6 1.5-Ohm, 1/4 Watt resistors in parallel and read 66mV. Multiplied by 4, that's a reading of 264mA. Do I need to add more resistors to get a more accurate reading?

Comment: Ah, silly me. 6 1.5 Ohm resistors = 0.125 Ohms. So I'm still saturating the CT.

Comment: Well, I figured it out. Going with your suggestion, I found that a 2Ft, 9In 22AWG stranded wire is approximately 0.04Ohms. Testing with that as my resistor, I read 12.8mV. 12.8mV * 25 = 320mA of current, which is pretty damn close. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Core saturation voltage is read with high Rout at low input current.  66mV is not conditon of core saturation. Output VA into 0.25 ohms is only 0.017W or VA and rating is 1.0VA so your burden R is too low for an accurate low current reading.  If you had 50A primary on line wire only <1VA out max , 5A secondary thus Rb<=1/(5*5) Ohm  For 5A primary full scale, use <1VA for accuracy and Rb <= 1/(0.5*.5A)=4 ohms.  Next use linear current not pulsed so DMM peak to RMS scaling is correct.